# Simplifying a process of formatting a date in order to take the value of the information in the same row and utilise it on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So to clarify, I track the site performance for the company I work by exporting the data from a 3rd party tool that tracks it every hour. I average these out to a weekly value and put those into excel. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCFFe.png), the fields at the top are the site performance metrics I track.

It's a bit complicated since the data I export can only be done so weekly or monthly, I cant specify a date range. To make it a bit easier I paste the values from the export into another sheet and get the week number by utilising the field from the export that has the [date and time of when it captured the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbka4.png) on the SS I use the yellow higlighted "Date (new)" field with  `=LEFT(Cx,10)` to simplify the date, then the "Week" field just uses `=WEEKNUM(Ux,21)` to get the week number from that simplified date.

Now that I have the week number for the values, I use `=AVERAGEIFS('Homepage - Desktop'!K:K,'Homepage - Desktop'!$B:$B,"Homepage - desktop",'Homepage - Desktop'!$V:$V,Summaries!$C5)` to automatically get the [average value for the week numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQCI.png) the "Homepage - desktop" corresponds with the sheet holding the value for that website page, there's 5 more for different web pages following the same logic.

The issue with this is that its still a manually heavy task, for each of the 6 pages there's the desktop and mobile metrics. And I have to copy/paste the formula onto the export to get the weekly number every single time, then copy all the data for the week number I need and paste it onto the respective web page sheet. Is there a way to make this simpler or even automate this process?

Comment: Simpler for who? and simpler how? I think the options are (in no particular order) power query in excel, power BI (with underying power query) or another BI program, and finally VBA (or office scripts if this is a web version).

Comment: Or even Python, there are at least one or two to get (extract) the web-data, then use "pandas" to juggle the data, and any Excel -read/create/modify module if you wish so.